# How to Install and Run eclipse on ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install the eclipse modelling tools on ubuntu. I have downloaded the eclipse from the eclipse site and I have extracted the file. I can see the eclipse icon but I cannot run it. I think I need to install it first but, I don't know how. I am new to the unix world.

I think I should first configure and do something like `make` so that it will be installed; Can someone please help me? I googled a lot, but I didn't find any complete answer for this problem.

Comment: do you have java installed?

Comment: which version of ubuntu and eclipse you are using?

Comment: You don't click on eclipse icon in folder only on eclipse executable which is just "eclipse"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I give you the Installation procedure of Eclipse 3.7 on Ubuntu 11.04.

1) [Download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)  Eclipse. I got eclipse-SDK-3.7-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

2) Extract it

```
tar xzf eclipse-SDK-3.7-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
```

Or just be lazy and Right Click > Extract Here

3) Move to /opt/ folder

```
 sudo mv eclipse /opt/
 sudo cd /opt/
 sudo chown -R root:root eclipse
 sudo chmod -R +r eclipse
```

4) Create an eclipse executable in your path

```
sudo touch /usr/bin/eclipse
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/eclipse
sudo nano /usr/bin/eclipse
```

copy this into nano

```
#!/bin/sh
#export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME="/usr/lib/mozilla/"
export ECLIPSE_HOME="/opt/eclipse"

$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse $*
```

save the file (^O = Ctrl+o) and exit nano (^X = Ctrl+x)

5) Create a gnome menu item

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

copy this into nano

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse IDE
Exec=eclipse
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;Application;Development;
StartupNotify=true
```

save and exit nano

6) Launch Eclipse for the first time

```
/opt/eclipse/eclipse -clean &
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: seems some senior had given this to you at start...

Comment: its giving permission denied for last command /opt/eclipse/eclipse -clean &
please help

Comment: It is about your permission issues. pl try with sudo, Rahul.

Comment: How can we make a shortcut to launch eclipse on desktop?

Comment: What does sudo chown -R root:root eclipse
 sudo chmod -R +r eclipse do?

Comment: It works on Debian 8 too!

Answer (score 5):

I've written an installer for Eclipse: https://github.com/bepcyc/eclipse_installer

Just download the eclipse archive (.tar.gz) to the same directory as the script and run:

```
./eclipse_installer.sh
```

It should work for any version of Eclipse and Linux.

Comment: /opt/eclipse/eclipse: 1: /opt/eclipse/eclipse: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Comment: I get the above error when I run `/usr/bin/eclipse -clean &` finally

Comment: @SathishKumarkk Thanks for using the script! Could you please file an issue on github page of the project?

Comment: what can I say , it cant be any simpler than this. Thanks a ton mate


u guys are the reason that we are so lazy ,,, just kidding !
Thanks again

Comment: @user3123372 thanks for using my script, hope it still works. 
You can also do `umake ide eclipse` or even `umake ide eclipse-jee` on a modern Ubuntu version. It even upgrades it ;)